# Отсортировать массив при помощи Comparator

Tags: java

Само задание звучит так: Реализовать программу чтения из текстового файла целых положительных значений (числа разделены пробелами, следует читать до конца файла), занесение этих чисел в массив, сортировка по убыванию и по возрастанию суммы цифр и хранения обоих результатов в двух новых текстовых файлах. Перечисленные действия реализовать в отдельной статической функции. Для определения порядка сортировки создать классы, которые реализуют интерфейс Comparator.

Я реализовала чтение из файла, занесение в массив, сортировку по возрастанию, но вот я не могу понять, как для определения порядка сортировки создать классы, которые реализуют интерфейс Comparator. Насколько я понимаю,сортировку по убыванию надо тоже как-то через Comparator.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void funk()throws FileNotFoundException{
    String path = 
"C:\\Users\\Ira\\Desktop\\PROGRAMMS\\JAVA\\1\\2\\out\\zfr.txt";
    File file = new File(path);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] numbersString = line.split(" ");
    int[] numbers = new int[numbersString.length];
    int[] numberss = new int[numbersString.length];
    int counter = 0;
    for (String number : numbersString) {
        numbers[counter++] = Integer.parseInt(number);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    scanner.close();
    System.out.print("[");
    for (int j=0;j<numbers.length;j++){
        int sum=0;
        while(numbers[j] != 0){
            sum += (numbers[j] % 10);
            numbers[j]/=10;
        }
        numberss[j]=sum;
        System.out.print(numberss[j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
    java.util.Arrays.sort (numberss);

    System.out.print("[");
    for (int j=0;j<numbers.length;j++) {
        System.out.print(numberss[j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    funk();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо создать два класса, реализовать в них интерфейс Comparator, если у целочисленный значения в массиве типа Integer, то можно сразу типизировать Comparator.

```
class Test implements Comparator<Integer>
```

далее в этом же классе реализуем метод compare(). Если сразу типизировать интерфейс, как я выше написал, то метод уже сам подставит нужный тип.

а в методе уже реализовать сортировку, например return o2 - o1; отсортирует по убыванию, о1 - о2 отсортирует по возрастанию.

```
static class Test implements Comparator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o2-o1;
    }
}
```

Далее в главном классе уже можно использовать классы-компораторы
У метода Arrays.sort есть конструктор, подаем массив данных и класс-компоратор.

```
Arrays.sort(test, new Test());
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю в Arrays.sort(test, new Test()); test - название массива, который будет сортироваться.

Comment: public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o2-o1; }        тут надо насколько я понимаю поменять переменные, как значения массива. Или я что-то не так поняла?

Comment: Так ли то, что я написала? Или не надо их делать эл массива.

Comment: test-да, это ваш массив. Остальное не надо, компилятор сам будет подставлять в о1 о2 значения массивов. Вам ничего делать не надо

Comment: `(o1 - o2)` - так нельзя сравнивать!!! Что если `o1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE`, а `o2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE`? Правильно так: `Integer.compare(o1, o2)`

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Согласен полностью, показал простое, не учитывая это.